# How do I resolve Promise in mocked function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to test method which returns Promise and resolves in another method which I want to mock.
I can test it without mocking but I don't want to because of credentials which wouldn't work on another machine.

Here's my Service code (**PollyService.ts**):

```
@Service()
export class PollyService {
    @Inject()
    private polly: Polly; // aws-sdk Polly
    url: string;

    getSpeech(body: any) {
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            let voice: string = (voices as any)[body.code];

            let params = {
               exampleParam: example
            };

            this.polly.synthesizeSpeech(params, (error: any, data: any) => {
                if (error) throw error;
                else {
                    resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Here's test (**app.spec.ts**)

```
describe('PollyService', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        Container.reset();
    });
    it ('Should return data', async () => {
        const event: any = {
            body: {
                sentence: "potato",
                code: "en"
            }
        };
        let polly = Container.get(Polly); // aws-sdk polly 
        spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech'); // and here I want to resolve Promise

        await Container.get(PollyService).getSpeech(event.body);
    });
});
```

When I am mocking that without resolving promise there is error:

*Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)*

How can i simulate resolving Promise in tests?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a promise which is already resolved, you can simply use `Promise.resolve(someData)`

In your case it should be something like this:

```
spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve('mockedData'));
```

Note: You get the timeout error message because you are neither returning the promise in the end of your function nor make use of the done callback.

either do:

```
    ...
    return await Container.get(PollyService).getSpeech(event.body);
```

or

```
describe('PollyService', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        Container.reset();
    });
    it ('Should return data', async (done) => { // <- done is the callback
        const event: any = {
            body: {
                sentence: "potato",
                code: "en"
            }
        };
        let polly = Container.get(Polly);
        spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech');

        await Container.get(PollyService).getSpeech(event.body);
        done(); // <- calling it will tell jasmine your test is over
    });
});
```

Usually either you choose to return the promise or use the callback. I am not sure on how jasmine mix async methods and the callback in the same method but it should work. More information [here](https://jasmine.github.io/tutorials/async)

Comment: Thank you for response. When I am trying to `spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve({}));`
I am facing error _TS2345: Argument of type: 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to parametr of type 'Request<SynthesizeSpeechOutgput, AWSError>'_

I have noticed it's working when I do something like that:
`spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech').and.callFake((param: any, fn: any ) => fn());`
but I have checked it with @ts-ignore. Without of course there is another TS2345 error.

Comment: that's because {} is an empty object and therefore not of the expected type `Request<SynthesizeSpeechOutgput, AWSError>`. Try using `null` instead if you really want to return an empty data one or create a `requestFactory()` method returning a data of the right type only for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend the `spyOn` with `and.returnValue` as follows:

```
const data = ... // define the data to be returned by synthesizeSpeech
spyOn(polly, 'synthesizeSpeech').and.returnValue(Promise.resolve(data));
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but I am facing _TS2345: Argument of type: 'Promise<{}>' is not assignable to parametr of type 'Request<SynthesizeSpeechOutgput, AWSError>' _ with that. I don't know how to resolve the types problem.